# Mapbox Satellite - Digitizing

Tags: mapbox, imagery, digitizing, license, services

As a part of project scope we have to deliver to the Client digitized data sets – some houses and roads. Can we use Mapbox Satellite global imagery layer [1] under Professional plan [2] for feature digitizing?

1. https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-satellite/
2. https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/

Answer (score 4):

No. You need a Mapbox Commercial Satellite licence.

[https://www.mapbox.com/tos/#[YmtIyw]](https://www.mapbox.com/tos/#%5BYmtIyw%5D)

> You may trace Mapbox-hosted imagery in order to produce derivative vector datasets for non-commercial purposes, and for OpenStreetMap. If you wish to produce derivative vector datasets from imagery for commercial purposes, you must buy a Mapbox Commercial Satellite license.

On [that page](https://www.mapbox.com/satellite/) it says:

> Commercial Data Ownership
>
> Any vector data you extract is owned by you. You can do anything you want with it — sell it, use it privately, open it up to the world, anything — forever. You'll have 100% ownership and control of your data and any vector derivatives are your own intellectual property. No restrictions.

Comment: On that page: "It's simple: our Commercial Satellite Derivative Data License covers the number of features you paid for. ... Pricing is based on the number of features you are planning to extract."        - It's not clear how I can use this plan for digitizing in QGIS and other Desktop GIS?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it starts at $2/feature and goes down. But your question was "can I use Mapbox satellite imagery for commercial feature extraction on the Professional plan" and the answer is no.